# Busybox Bitbake Config does not save

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, busybox

I am trying to add devmem to my yocto image. I do this I run the command

```
bitbake -c menuconfig busybox
```

I go to Miscellaneous Utilities and place a * in the devmem menu. Exit and save the config then perform a

```
bitbake busybox
```

Followed by

```
bitbake core-image-full-cmdline
```

When I boot my device the `devmem` program is not there, when I re-run the `menuconfig` for busybox the `devmem` option is no longer selected! What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Busybox` is like other projects that are using a `.config` to define the features needed to be compiled into the final output, just like the Linux kernel and U-boot, etc.

So, here how to deal with them in Yocto:

When you run:

```
bitbake busybox -c menuconfig
```

it will run `make menuconfig` into its working directory and opens the configuration menu for you.

Now, if you save and exit, only the `.config` in the working directory will be changed, meaning that if the recipe get unpacked again your modification will be lost.

In addition, when you change the `.config` via `menuconfig` you need to force the compilation of the `busybox` recipe, because for bitbake it is already built:

```
bitbake busybox -c compile -f
```

But, for the best practices, here what I suggest to you if you want your modification to be a feature that you can easily enable or disable from a recipe:

1. Run: `bitbake busybox -c menuconfig`
2. Edit and save your modification
3. Run: `bitbake busybox -c diffconfig`

The `diffconfig` command will give you a `fragment.cfg` file that contains the modifications you just did.

The file should contain:

```
CONFIG_DEVMEM=y
```

A quick explaination about the fragment:

When you opened `menuconfig` it backed up `.config` to `.config.old`, and then `diffconfig` will give you the difference between them after saving your modification into `.config`.

Now, Busybox like other recipes that are using configuration files, they understand that if a `.cfg` file exists in their working directory, they need to apply it to their main `.config` file before compilation.

So, what you need to do after getting the `fragment.cfg` is to create a `.bbappend` recipe to `busybox` in your custom recipe and specify your new fragment:

```
meta-custom/
     | recipes-core/
         | busybox/
             | busybox_%.bbappend
             | busybox/
                 | devmem.cfg
```

Now, `busybox_%.bbappend` contains:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://devmem.cfg"
```

Now, when you re-bitbake Busybox again, it will unpack the fragment and apply it.

To check if the fragment is applied after the bitbake completes, you can check the `.config` file:

1. First get the Build directory path of Busybox

```
bitbake -e busybox | grep ^B=
```

2. Grep for CONFIG_DEVMEM

```
grep CONFIG_DEVMEM <path_of_previous_command>/.config
```

You should see:

```
CONFIG_DEVMEM=y
```

Comment: This is amazing and incredibly detailed. I am going through your steps to make my changes and force a re-compile. When I run the diffconfig I am told not original config file is found. I am running in the build directory.

Comment: This worked! Your steps are perfect!